# Why gin (golang) makes my custom header lowercase?

Tags: http, go, http-headers

I'm stuck on this problem while learning go/gin. When I use custom header gin makes it lowercase, here is code example:

```
package main

import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

func main() {
    r := gin.New()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Header("X-Next", "abc")
        c.String(200, "ok")
    })
    r.Run(":9000")
}
```

Header becomes `x-next`, can't figure it out why it is happening. Similar example with standard `http` module works fine.

Comment: Where are you seeing this? `gin.Context.Header` just calls `http.ResponseWriter.Header.Set` underneath. Testing with `curl -v http://localhost:9000/ping` returns a verbatim `X-Next: abc` as expected. I suspect your browser is just lowercasing it—which is not a problem as headers should not be case-sensitive.

Comment: Yes, looks like its browser. Probably browser lower cases "non standard" headers.

Comment: Does it matter? Headers in HTTP are case-insensitive. Treating them as case-sensitive is always a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its browser changes case of header, and it is not an issue with gin. Thanks @elithrar for hint.

Comment: It's not an issue anyway; header field names are case-insensitive.